# Next JS & NextAuth - JavaScript onClick Not Working in Navbar on server start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am building an app and I'm implementing a feature that the user can log in with google using next auth. When I first start the server and navigate to localhost:3000, I am unable to click on the button to signIn. It is only when I navigate to a different route or reload the page that it works.I tried to test this by adding a console.log when using onClick but it didn't work, not logged to the console.

Navbar

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Dialog } from "@headlessui/react";
import { Bars3Icon, XMarkIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import Link from "next/link";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

import AvatarDropdown from "../auth/AvatarDropdown";

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

const navigation = [
  { name: "Generate", href: "/generate" },
  { name: "Pricing", href: "/pricing" },
  { name: "Community", href: "/community" },
  { name: "Collection", href: "/collection" },
];

const Navbar = () => {
  const { status, data: session } = useSession();

  const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="bg-white">
      <header className="absolute inset-x-0 top-0 z-50">
        <nav
          className="flex items-center justify-between p-6 lg:px-20"
          aria-label="Global"
        >
          <div className="flex lg:flex-1">
            <Link href="/" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
              <span className="sr-only">Your Company</span>
              <img
                className="h-8 w-auto"
                src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
                alt=""
              />
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="flex lg:hidden">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="-m-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
              onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(true)}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
              <Bars3Icon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:gap-x-12">
            {navigation.map((item) => (
              <Link
                key={item.name}
                href={item.href}
                className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                {item.name}
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:flex-1 lg:justify-end">
            {session?.user ? (
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <p className=" mr-3 text-sm">10 credits left</p>

                <AvatarDropdown session={session} />
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => signIn("google")}
                  className="rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3.5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
                >
                  Sign in
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </nav>
        <Dialog
          as="div"
          className="lg:hidden"
          open={mobileMenuOpen}
          onClose={setMobileMenuOpen}
        >
          <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50" />
          <Dialog.Panel className="fixed inset-y-0 right-0 z-50 w-full overflow-y-auto bg-white px-6 py-6 sm:max-w-sm sm:ring-1 sm:ring-gray-900/10">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
              <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
                <span className="sr-only">Your Company</span>
                <img
                  className="h-8 w-auto"
                  src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
                  alt=""
                />
              </a>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="-m-2.5 rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
                onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(false)}
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Close menu</span>
                <XMarkIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-6 flow-root">
              <div className="-my-6 divide-y divide-gray-500/10">
                <div className="space-y-2 py-6">
                  {navigation.map((item) => (
                    <Link
                      key={item.name}
                      href={item.href}
                      className="-mx-3 block rounded-lg px-3 py-2 text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50"
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </Link>
                  ))}
                </div>
                <div className="py-6">
                  <Link
                    href="/login"
                    className="rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3.5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
                  >
                    Log in
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Dialog.Panel>
        </Dialog>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

layout.js

```
import { NextAuthProvider } from "./Provider";
import Navbar from "./components/shared/Navbar";
import { GenerateIconProvider } from "./context/GenerateIconContext";
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <NextAuthProvider>
          <GenerateIconProvider>
            <Navbar />
            <main>{children}</main>
          </GenerateIconProvider>
        </NextAuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default RootLayout;
```